# Why is the "$\phi$" equation not differentiated with the affine parameter in Schwarzschild case?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, geodesics

The equation for motion determined by the Lagrangian formulation takes the form:
$$L^2 = g_{ab}\frac{dx^a}{dm}\frac{dx^b}{dm}$$

We arrive, for the $\phi$ coordinate in $(t, r, \theta , \phi)$ system of Schwarzschild metric at the equation (which is given in the book):
$$r^2 sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi} = h$$
which is a result of using the EL equation:
$$\frac{d}{dm}\partial_{\dot{\phi}} L^2 + \partial_{\phi} L^2 = 0 $$

Now, i understand that $L^2$ isn't a function of the $\phi$ and hence the second term would vanish but, shouldn't the first term be differentiated again with the affine parameter and hence the answer should be:

$$\ddot{\phi} +  2 cot\theta \dot{\theta}\dot{\phi} + 2 \dot{r} \dot{\phi}$$

instead of the given one?

References:
General relativity: MP Hobson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, $\phi$ is cyclic. So the EL equation's LHS is $0$, but one term of it is trivially $0$, and the other is also $0$. And if you delete its $\frac{d}{dm}$, you get something conserved - a conserved momentum, in fact. In this case, that conservation law is $h:=\tfrac12\partial_{\dot\phi }L^2=r^2\sin^2\theta\dot{\phi}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $h$ is the conserved momentum quantity? Is it because the $\dot{\phi} = 0$ and hence the conserved quantity is momentum? But then, shouldn’t it be angular momentum conservation in that case?

Comment: @mnuizhre $h$ is conserved because $\partial_\phi L^2=0$. This conservation law allows you to impose a coordinate choice in which this conserved quantity is $0$, so that $\dot{\phi}=0$. But more generally, $h\ne0$, so $\dot{\phi}\ne0$. A cyclic coordinate implies some _canonical_ momentum is conserved; in this case, it's also an _angular_ momentum, as opposed to a _linear_ momentum. That's because the symmetry is rotational, not translational.

Comment: Yes, exactly my point, it should be angular momentum. In the answer of yours you have mentioned momentum. Thanks!

Comment: @mnuizhre There's no contradiction. It's a "momentum" _in the sense of Lagrangian mechanics_ , but that doesn't prohibit it also having other names.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks for the clarification.